# Division of a color image into blocks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i have an RGB image of size 256X256.I need to divide this RGB image into blocks of size 32X32.each block must be in turn an RGB image.how can i do this in MATLAB.Please provide me code for this in MATLAB.

Comment: We're here to help you solve problems, not do them for you.  What have you done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Donnie: oops. Well, if @sushmi is interested in the problem, they will spend some time trying to understand the solution and learn something from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mat2cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html) for this.

```
out = mat2cell(image,ones(256/32,1)*32,ones(256/32,1)*32,3);
```

`out` is a 8-by-8 [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html), with each cell containing a 32-by-32-by-3 RGB image.

You can access the first block as `out{1,1}`.

**EDIT**

Changed `repmat` to `ones` to make the code faster.

Comment: I usually prefer using ONES instead of REPMAT in cases like this, like "32*ones(1,8)". But I guess it's just a matter of preference. ;)

Comment: @gnovice: I had thought I had read somewhere that it's better to use `repmat` instead of multiplying by `ones(x)`, but looking at the code of `repmat` makes me think that using `ones(x)` should be faster ...*checks*... yep, it's about twice as fast.